# Looking for a platformer game

Tags: identify-this-game

All I can remember of the game is that:

- It was a platformer game
- The game might have been made in the 90's
- I *think* it was a DOS game
- It was a very colored game
- The main character was human (I think it was a female character)
- **I think I had to collect letters or some item to transform into animals and progress in the game -> A fish to explore the water, a bird to fly, etc.**
- I barely remember the word **JILJ** but I'm not able to find anything about this in a web search engine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This sounds like [Jill of the Jungle](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/jill-of-the-jungle):

> It is a platform game where the player takes the role of the titular character: an amazon woman who takes the untypical role of monster-slaying, leather-wearing feminist warrior. Jill's most distinguishing ability is morphing into various creatures, such as a bird, a fish, and others, which allow her to explore specific areas.

This is a DOS game, released in 1992 (as shareware). It is indeed very colourful, and its main character is a woman. You need to find “icons” to turn into various animals, and to turn back into Jill.

It’s available [for free on GOG](https://www.gog.com/game/jill_of_the_jungle_the_complete_trilogy).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I was looking for this game since many years now and wasn't able to find anyone to help me.

Comment: Based on a manual for the game the executable was named `JILL.EXE`, but the `JILJ` that OP remembers is pretty close.

Comment: Maybe the data files were `JILJLVL1.DAT` etc

Comment: You can also [play the game in your browser on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/JillOfTheJungle).

Comment: @pipe that could have been it, but the files are named `1.jn1`, `2.jn1`, `1.jn2` etc., `jill1.*`...; nothing with `jilj`.